# how can I get clang to vectorize a simple loop?

Tags: c, clang, vectorization, compiler-optimization, sse

I have the following loop:

```
float* s;
float* ap;
float* bp;

... // initialize s, ap, bp

for(size_t i=0;i<64;++i) {
   s[i] = ap[i]+bp[i];
}
```

Seems like a good candidate for vectorization. Though I have optimization turned on, when I look at the assembly output, clang (I'm using Xcode) seems to not have vectorized the loop:

```
LBB33_1:                                ## =>This Inner Loop Header: Depth=1
    movss   (%rax,%rsi,4), %xmm0    ## xmm0 = mem[0],zero,zero,zero
    addss   (%rcx,%rsi,4), %xmm0
    movss   %xmm0, (%rdx,%rsi,4)
Ltmp353:
    incq    %rsi
Ltmp354:
    cmpq    $64, %rsi
Ltmp355:
    jne LBB33_1
```

**How can I get clang/Xcode to vectorize this simple loop?**

Comment: Did you try using `float *restrict s` so it knows the output doesn't overlap the inputs?  With a small iteration count, it might decide it's not worth emitting code to check for (lack of) overlap and having 2 versions.

Comment: @PeterCordes that alone does not change the output. Perhaps I need to ensure the pointers are aligned?

Comment: It might help to *promise the compiler* they're aligned, with `ap = __builtin_assume_aligned(ap, 32)` or similar, but usually that's not the deciding factor in auto-vectorizing or not.  It will give you more efficient code-gen without AVX, though.

Answer (score 14):

**Use a non-ancient version of clang/LLVM**.  Apple clang/LLVM is different from mainline clang/LLVM, but they share a common codebase.

Mainline clang3.3 and newer auto-vectorize your loop at `-O3`.  **Clang3.4 and newer auto-vectorize it even at `-O2`.**

Without `restrict`, clang *does* emit asm that checks for overlap between the destination and the two sources (with a fallback to scalar), so you'll get more efficient asm from `float *restrict s`.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
void add_float_good(float *restrict s, float *restrict ap, float *restrict bp)
{
    for(size_t i=0;i<64;++i) {
       s[i] = ap[i]+bp[i];
    }
}
```

compiles [with clang3.4 -O3 (on the Godbolt compiler explorer)](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:'%23include+%3Cstdint.h%3E%0A%23include+%3Cstdlib.h%3E%0A%0Avoid+add_float_good(float+*restrict+s,+float+*restrict+ap,+float+*restrict+bp)+%7B%0A++++%0A++++for(size_t+i%3D0%3Bi%3C64%3B%2B%2Bi)+%7B%0A+++++++s%5Bi%5D+%3D+ap%5Bi%5D%2Bbp%5Bi%5D%3B%0A++++%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Avoid+add_float(float*+s,+float*+ap,+float*+bp)+%7B%0A++++%0A++++for(size_t+i%3D0%3Bi%3C64%3B%2B%2Bi)+%7B%0A+++++++s%5Bi%5D+%3D+ap%5Bi%5D%2Bbp%5Bi%5D%3B%0A++++%7D%0A%7D'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:34.86495102939401,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang341,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!((name:boost,ver:'169')),options:'-std%3Dgnu99+-xc+-O2+-Wall',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+clang+3.4.1+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:31.80171563727267,l:'4',m:100,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang800,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!((name:boost,ver:'169')),options:'-xc+-O3+-Wall+-march%3Dskylake',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+clang+8.0.0+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%232)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:33.33333333333333,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',m:100,n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4) to this simplistic asm with the worst of indexed addressing modes and loop overhead, but at least it's vectorized.  Newer clang likes to unroll, especially when tuning for recent Intel (e.g. `-march=skylake`)

```
# clang3.4 -O3
add_float_good:
        xor     eax, eax
.LBB0_1:                                # %vector.body
        movups  xmm0, xmmword ptr [rsi + 4*rax]
        movups  xmm1, xmmword ptr [rdx + 4*rax]
        addps   xmm1, xmm0
        movups  xmmword ptr [rdi + 4*rax], xmm1
        add     rax, 4
        cmp     rax, 64
        jne     .LBB0_1
        ret
```

Notice that without AVX, it can't use a memory-source operand for `addps` because there's no compile-time alignment guarantee.

clang8.0 -O3 -march=skylake fully unrolls with YMM vectors, like gcc with the same options.

Answer (score 1):

It’s probably best to make this explicit, using Accelerate. In this case, vDSP_vadd will do the trick.